# Centos 7 no input in grub serial console

Tags: centos, centos7, grub2

I use serial over lan console on intel S1200V3RPL server board. It worked nicely, but filesystem got corrupted and I had to reinstall. I've setup serial console the same way,but there is no input in grub2. Input works in BIOS and centos console after boot, but not in group. I can't select other option or interrupt the boot process. After boot I can login and everything works fine.

```
# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="serial console"
# I tried with and without following line
#GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

The only difference is that I installed previous CentOS via EFI and now is legacy boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="serial console"

Change this to:

GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"

(also you have a duplicate GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT; remove it)

Comment: Grub now outputs to the console, but the OS doesn't - this doesn't work: `console=ttyS0,115200n8`

Comment: It's a shell script variables - the second one overrides the previous. I keep the previous for reference what was the default. I have no idea why "_OUTPUT" is appended. Maybe I followed a tutorial.

Comment: I changed the motherboard and I didn't check carefully bios settings. The new motherboard outputs Serial-over-lan to ttyS1, not ttyS0. All works now. Thanks